# Accessing a local service IP adress (not localhost) from Google Cloud VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I have a Google Cloud VM instance with local services running on localhost:9000, localhost:8081 and 172.18.0.5:8090. To access the first two remotely, I just use external-ip:9000 and external-ip:8081 in my browser, but the third one I don't know how to access. All ports are allowed in the firewall settings. I have tried external-ip:8090, but I don't get access.

How can I access this local IP address 172.18.0.5:8090 from my own machine?

Comment: Are you referring to the internal IP address? What error are you encountering when doing so?

Comment: I don't think so since the internal IP cannot be accessed remotely, right? Although I'm not an expert on this. When i try to reach external-ip:8090, I just don't get any connection in my browser. Do you suggest I try to access internal-ip:8090 through my browser?

Comment: No, How did you setup the local IP 172.18.0.5? iptables and firewalld? Does it have a port forwarding?